# Do amoebas obtain extra tentacles as we take the tropical limit?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

**Original Question**

In this question, we'll restrict ourselves to plane curves.

Define the $t$-amoeba of a polynomial $p(z,w) = \sum_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}} a_{ij} z^i w^j$ to be the set $\mathcal{A}_t(p) = \{ (\log_t |z|, \log_t |w|) : (z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2, p(z,w) = 0 \}$ (as defined in [Gatthman's notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601322.pdf)).

As we take the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} \mathcal{A}_t(p)$, we expect a tropical curve to appear, with a degree $d$ polynomial having $d$ branches in the south, west, and northeast directions. For example, a degree 2 curve should degenerate to something like

[image: From Gatthman's notes]

Yet, when we look at pictures of Amoebas, say in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_(mathematics)), we don't see this regularity. For instance, in Wikipedia there's the example of the degree 3 polynomial

$P(z,w) = 3z^2+5zw+w^3+1$

having amoeba

[image: From Wikepedia]

In this case, which is $\mathcal{A}_e(P)$, we don't see the three tentacles in each standard direction. Coupled with that, there's this *vacuole*. Do the three tentacles we expect appear as we take the limit? What happens to the vacuole? Is there a specific $t$ when these tentacles appear and you start to see the tropical structure emerge in the spine?

**Edit**

I think these pictures might not have all the tentacles because the tentacles are overlapping. Is there a way to tell if a polynomial leads to a degenerate amoeba/tropical curve with some tentacles having multiplicity?

**Expanded Answer**

Thanks to Marco Golia's answer, I think I understand my misconception. I see now that we should expect any individual amoeba to converge to a tropical vertex - i.e., the tropical curve associated to a polynomial of form $$ \bigoplus_{i=1}^n z^{\odot a_z^{(i)}}\odot w^{\odot a_w^{(i)}} = \max \{ a_z^{(i)}z+a_w^{(i)}w : i=1,\dots,n \}$$ with $a_z^{(i)},a_w^{(i)} \in \mathbb{N}$. Every tropical plane curve can be viewed as a balanced graph, with vertices locally being of this form.

I've written code in Mathematica that allows you to generate these vertices/curves along with the convex hull associated to them [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/kevintang634489/Published/subdivision.nb). I'll post the results for some of the Wikipedia amoebas below. Like Peter Taylor hinted in a comment, everything is just scaled down to the origin, and a lot of the tentacles collapse onto each other (as they get infinitely close to each other).

*Amoeba*

$P(z,w) = 3z^2+5zw+w^3+1$

[image: From Wikepedia]

*Tropical Curve Associated*

[image: combinedPlot[{{2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 3, 0}}]]

*Amoeba*

$P(z,w) = 50z^3 + 83z^2w + 24zw^2 + w^3 + 392z^2 + 414zw + 50w^2 - 28z + 59w - 100$

[image: From Wikipedia]

*Tropical Curve Associated*

[image: combinedPlot[{{3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0}}]]

Finally, for one last example

*Amoeba*

$P(z, w) = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^2w^3 + 10zw + 12z^2w + 10z^2w^2$

[image: From Wikipedia]

*Tropical Curve Associated*

[image: combinedPlot[{{0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2}}]]

**Note**

The image descriptions of the Tropical Curve should have the code input I used, and the Mathematica notebook should have sufficient description to what the code is outputting.

For more information/context, you can also view this short [exposition](https://mijucik.notion.site/Tropical-Plane-Curves-55b33c4ad95f4ef9be250627b87dc95d) I wrote.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely changing the base of the logarithm just scales the diagram?

Comment: I think you're right - maybe these are degenerate cases and the extra tentacles I'm thinking of are on top of each other.

Comment: That's not a degree 2 polynomial.  Note the term w³.

Comment: You're right. I've edited it.

Comment: May be worth trying to ask the title question at Biology.SE as well :)

Comment: The evolutionary limit haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a complete answer and I'm not an expert, but it's way too long for a comment.

For a while I had the same misconception you have now, until Erwan Brugallé set me straight: there's no tropical curve associated to a complex curve. Rather, a tropical curve is associated to a *degenerating family* of complex curves. In your expression $\sum a_{ij}x^iy^j$, the $a_{ij}$ are supposed to be polynomials (or power series that converge around 0) in the variable $t$. Then you're taking the limit of a *family* of amoebas, and not a single amoeba. (Indeed, as Peter Taylor points out, if you did that this would degenerate to a tropical line with multiplicity.)

As for the way of detecting tentacles/vacoules/slopes/multiplicities, one gets a polygonal subdivision of the Newton polygon of the polynomial (the convex hull of the pairs $(i,j)$ for which $a_{ij} \neq 0$) which (if memory serves me well) comes from how fast $a_{ij}$ converges as $t\to 0$. The tropical curve in the limit is dual to this subdivision. This is much better explained in Brugallé and Shaw's notes [here](http://erwan.brugalle.perso.math.cnrs.fr/articles/Quadrature/quadratureEng.pdf), in Section 5.

For the record, the vacuoles correspond to the genus of the complex curves in the family. For a non-singular tropical curve of degree $d$, the number of vacuoles that persist is $b_1$ of the corresponding graph (i.e. the number of cycles) and agrees with the genus of the corresponding complex curve (i.e. any of the non-singular complex curves in the family), which is $(d-1)(d-2)/2$. So, for a non-singular cubic, one vacuole, as in your example.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I think of it, limits of individual amoebas should converge to the tropical curve associated to a tropical polynomial of form $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n x^{\odot a_x^{(i)}}\odot y^{\odot a_y^{(i)}} = \max \{ a_x^{(i)}x+a_y^{(i)}y : i=1,\dots,n \}$ (since $\log_t|a_{ij}|  \to 0$ for all $a_{ij}$). Interestingly, if we consider a tropical curve as a balanced graph, each vertex of a tropical curve locally looks like this. Only when we consider families of amoebas, where $a_{ij}(t)$ should we expect to see more vertices emerge.

Comment: Also, thanks for your help! I've expanded on your answer in mine, and I've put in some examples above, generating limits of these amoebas.